# Why does FFT and Discrete Fourier Transform look completely different?

Tags: computational-physics, fourier-transform, software, discrete

I have a function

\begin{array}{@{} r @{} c @{} l @{} }
&f(t) &{}=\displaystyle
\begin{cases}
a(1-a|t|) &\text{if } \>\>|t|<\dfrac{1}{a}\\
0 &\text{if } \>\>|t|>\dfrac{1}{a}
\end{cases}
\end{array}

Here is what the function looks like for $a=2$:
[image: f(t)]

I wrote two scripts to evaluate the Fourier Transform of this function, $g(\omega)=\mathcal{F}[f(t)]$. One is simply a numerical integration of the standard Fourier Transform, and the other is an implementation of the Discrete Fourier Transform. Here are the results of running those two scripts, with the DFT on the top:
[image: g(w) - integration][image: g(w) - DFT]

Since these two look largely the same, minus some differences in normalization, I'm convinced my implementations are working properly. However, if I run an FFT on $f(t)$, and plot the result vs. frequency, it looks completely different than what I get from either other method of computation:

[image: fft]

Why is this? Shouldn't they look exactly the same? I mean the FFT is literally the DFT, just implemented in a cleverly optimized way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mad stupid wrong idea on my part I admit, but because it looks wiggley, how do both functions deal with the Gibbs phenomenon? You can just tell me it's not relevant, no need to waste your time if that's the case.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) is probably better.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano: That too.

Comment: In your first two plots I assume you are plotting the magnitude of the FT. Since the FT, FFT yield complex results, did you perhaps forget to take the magnitude of the FFT before plotting it?

Comment: I think this is essentially a plotting error.  It looks like you're computing the FFT by calling a function which returns first the zero value, then the positive values, then the negative values.  This is a common convention in signal processing.  You also need to take absolute values, as docscience points out, and you probably need to correct for normalization conventions.